# Error when trying to write an object to a file in libgdx

Tags: java, android, file, io, libgdx

I keep getting this error. I am trying to save one object to a file in libGDX. I first create the file then I create a new high score and save it. But it didn't work and I've tried making the Score class implement serializable and making the score object transient. Both didn't work. I tried running the desktop version on libGDX.

```
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: com.bayanijulian.covertpony.save.Score
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1355)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
at com.bayanijulian.covertpony.save.SaveHandler.load(SaveHandler.java:35)
```

There are my classes.

```
package com.bayanijulian.covertpony.save;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle;
import com.bayanijulian.covertpony.TSIEngine;

import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class SaveHandler{
    public static void save(){
        FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local("score.txt");

    try{
        ObjectOutputStream scoreOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(file.write(false));
        scoreOutput.writeObject(TSIEngine.score);
        scoreOutput.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        //TODO fix crash
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
public static void load(){
    FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local("score.txt");

    try{
        if(!file.exists()){
            file.file().createNewFile();
            TSIEngine.score = new Score("3:00","you");
            save();
        }
        ObjectInputStream scoreInput = new ObjectInputStream(file.read());
        TSIEngine.score = (Score) scoreInput.readObject();
        scoreInput.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        //TODO fix crash
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}


}
```

This is the Score object that I am trying to write to the file.

```
package com.bayanijulian.covertpony.save;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Score implements Serializable{
private String time;
private String name;

public Score(String time, String name) {
    this.time = time;
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}
}
```

Thanks for your time! Any help is greatly appreciated. I've been stuck on this forever. I just want to save one high score.

Comment: Your code as is works fine for me. Make sure you delete the old file before testing it again as it may be trying to load an old invalid version of your Score before it implemented Serializable.

Comment: I actually did more testing. Yes you are right, the code does work. But when I tried to read from the score object after loading it, it errors out because it says its a null object.

Comment: after deleting the file it created and re writing to it, it now works. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the LibGDX Preferences class instead:

https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Preferences.html

Here's the wiki tutorial on how to use it:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences